# Python recursion with nested loops

Tags: python, parsing, recursion

I have parse function which is parsing tree of categories. I've written it in simplest way possible and now struggling with refactoring it.

Every nested loop is doing the same stuff but appending object to object childs initialized at the top.

I think it's possible to refactor it with recursion but I'm struggling with it. How to wrap it in recursion function to prevent code duplication?

Final result should be a list of objects or just yield top level object with nested childs.

```py
for container in category_containers:
            root_category_a = container.xpath("./a")
            root_category_title = root_category_a.xpath("./*[1]/text()").get()
            root_category_url = self._host + root_category_a.xpath("./@href").get()

            root = {
                "title": root_category_title,
                "url": root_category_url,
                "childs": [],
            }

            subcategory_rows1 = container.xpath("./div/div")

            for subcat_row1 in subcategory_rows1:
                subcategory_a = subcat_row1.xpath("./a")
                subcategory_title = subcategory_a.xpath("./*[1]/text()").get()
                subcategory_url = self._host + subcategory_a.xpath("./@href").get()

                subcat1 = {
                    "title": subcategory_title,
                    "url": subcategory_url,
                    "childs": [],
                }

                subcategory_rows2 = subcat_row1.xpath("./div/div")

                for subcat_row2 in subcategory_rows2:
                    subcategory2_a = subcat_row2.xpath("./a")
                    subcategory2_title = subcategory2_a.xpath("./*[1]/text()").get()
                    subcategory2_url = self._host + subcategory2_a.xpath("./@href").get()
                    subcat2 = {
                        "title": subcategory2_title,
                        "url": subcategory2_url,
                        "childs": [],
                    }

                    subcategory_rows3 = subcat_row2.xpath("./div/div")

                    for subcat_row3 in subcategory_rows3:
                        subcategory3_a = subcat_row3.xpath("./a")
                        subcategory3_title = subcategory3_a.xpath("./*[1]/text()").get()
                        subcategory3_url = self._host + subcategory3_a.xpath("./@href").get()
                        subcat3 = {
                            "title": subcategory3_title,
                            "url": subcategory3_url,
                            "childs": [],
                        }

                        subcat2['childs'].append(subcat3)

                    subcat1['childs'].append(subcat2)

                root['childs'].append(subcat1)

            yield root
```

Comment: As your code is functional, it might be better to ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is a bunch of undefined variables in your code (all the `_title` and `_url`). [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: updated the code.

Comment: What's in `category_containers`?

Answer (score 0):

It is generally done as follows:

1. Prepare a container (list) to collect the parsed objects
2. Pass a reference to that object to the parsing function
3. Define the function as follows:

- The function accepts a category object and a reference to a container.
- Parse the category object and add it into the container using the reference.
- Iterate over all direct subcategories of that category object and call the function itself on each of it, using the same container reference you got as a parameter.
- You do not have to return anything, as the function fills the input container as a side-effect.

From now on, you can focus on how to rewrite the function to avoid side-effects, but for the concept implementation, this one is much better.